# Chaining promises in Angular with $q.all

Tags: angularjs

I have the following layout for a promise chain in a service...

```
this.getData = function(params) {
     var promise = $http({}).then(function(firstdata) {

      // work on the first data and then call a number of promises for fetch additional data
      var promises = list.map(function(item) {
        return $http({}).then(function(result2) {
          // this is an amalgamation of all the data from the various calls
          return finalData;
        });
        return $q.all(promises);  
      })
    });
    return promise;
  }
```

Then in my controller i'm doing

```
myService.getData().then(function(data){
});
```

The issue lies in the fact that THEN in the controller executes before PROMISES (note the plural) has returned a value.

This is likely something silly but any thoughts on how to simplify this/make it work would be handy!

Comment: Why do you have 2 promises being returned (1st is from `$http` call and second is from `$q.all`) from within the `.map` callbacks?

Comment: Because they need to execute sequentially?

Comment: So make first call->generate a number of others->amalgamate the data from the first and second call->return data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently your inner `promises`($q.all promise) isn't returned from promise variable. You should also return `promises`(plural), to make sure chain should work.

```
this.getData = function(params) {
    var promise = $http({}).then(function(firstdata) {

        // creating new promise array in `promises` function
        var promises = list.map(function(item) {
            return $http({}).then(function(result2) {
                // this is an amalgamation of all the data from the various calls
                return finalData;
            });
            return $q.all(promises); 
        });
        return promises; //returning inner promise
    });
    return promise;
}
```

Comment: Ohh dear, let me test this out, it's a huge function and that would make sense i've just missed one out..